# How to display console.log output in Visual Studio Code for html?

Tags: visual-studio-code, console.log

When I used brackets, there was a plugin to display `console.log` output in a panel below the source code panel, so I don't need switch to chrome and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to view `console.log` output.

But how to do that in Visual Studio Code?

I use Visual Studio Code for HTML development not **Node.js**.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`debugger-for-chrome` can solve the problem.
Check this link. It shows how to do that

--UPDATE--

Now VS code has built in debugging support for Javascript.

[image]

You can easily debug your application by clicking on the **Run and Debug button** as shown in the image. If you want to debug any other languages or runtimes, you need to install a debugger extension for that specified language or runtime in the VS code marketplace.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Comment: -1: Just putting a link to another site is not the kind of answer expected on SO. Giving a short explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: same, adding a site link is not what an answer should be

Comment: Well this answer is much better than nothing, and me and 5000 others are happy it exists, post a better one instead of down voting. Thanks Amila!

Comment: What if we are using IE11? How to see console.log messages in VS code itself ?

Comment: I have an electron app, the console.log on the main.js does show on VSCode console but all other console.log called from other .js files (mi app has 3 html & js) only appear on the browser console. FYI i'm using the debbuger for chrome extension. any ideas?

Comment: `debugger-for-chrome` is now deprecated in favour of `vscode-js-debug`

Comment: Not sure how this gives us `console.log()` output

Answer (score 13):

The vscode extension you want is [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server).

This gives you a HTML preview pane within vscode itself. To activate it:

1. Right-click on your HTML file, and select `Live Preview: Show Preview`. This is like a mini browser which will display your HTML. (Shown with red circle)

[image: select live preview]

---

2. To find your `console.log()` messages, select the `OUTPUT` tab, and from the drop-down, select `Embedded Live Preview Console` (Shown with red arrow)

[image: output console]

---

3. Finally, hit the "Refresh Arrow" in the preview pane, and you should see the `console.log()` output.

[image: refresh]

Comment: Should be the top answer now in the year 2022 (almost 2023), thank you very much!

Comment: why the hell I'm not seeing this "Embedded Live Preview" option, even though my live preview broser is open???????

Answer (score 3):

You could create an index.html and link to your .js in head then use Live Server with an "undock separate window."

Comment: A link to where you found this solution would also suffice.

Comment: There’s no link to where I found the solution. Install the Live Server extension so they when you save your .js file the Clothing browser automatically updates and prints console.log.

Comment: Just in case anyone needed more clarification for this method.  The VS code extension is called 'Live Server' by Ritwick Dey.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer .  Once you install this extension, you create your HTML file, link your JS file as usual. Then right click the HTML file and select 'Open with Live Server'.  A browser window will open showcasing your HTML file.  Right click on this window and select 'Inspect' to open the dev tools, then select 'Console'.  Your JavaScript Console logs will output here.

Comment: Not sure how this gives us `console.log()` output

Answer (score 0):

I have added the 'Code Runner' extension
Example:

1. Best dynamic one:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.quokka-vscode&ssr=false#review-details
2. Option:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner&ssr=false#review-details

There are also terminal commands you can run and output on the terminal too.

Comment: If [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) is installed then code runner shows the console logs